# SQL:How do I group by the ids with only the null directly located directly below it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I group by the ids with only the null directly located directly below it. Then get sum of the time?

```
ID    time
1     time1
null  time1
null  time1
null  time1
2     time1
null  time1
null  time1
3     time1
null  time1
null  time1
```

Result wanted

```
ID    time
1     sumTime
2     sumTime
3     sumTime
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  In order for you to do what you want, you need a column that specifies the ordering.  Once you have that, you can identify the groups by counting up the cumulative number of non-null values in `id` and aggregating:

```
select id, sum(time)
from (select t.*,
             count(id) over (order by <ordering col>) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

If you do not have an ordering column, your question does not make sense, because the table is unordered.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gordon Linoff that what you are asking falls outside the rules of SQL Server because tables in SQL Server are unordered sets.
However, assuming that if you run the command

```
SELECT * FROM YourTimeTable
```

returns the data following the order and structure you showed:

```
ID    time
1     time1
null  time1
null  time1
null  time1
2     time1
null  time1
null  time1
3     time1
null  time1
null  time1
```

You can make it work with the following strategy:
Add a new column with row numbers that we can use to add ordering
Then run an update statement to set the ID = to the highest ID in row numbers smaller than the current row number.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tempTimeTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
    drop table #tempTimeTable
end
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TIME) AS RowN, * into #tempTimeTable FROM YourTimeTable
update t1 set ID = (select max(ID) from #tempTimeTable t2 where t2.RowN < t1.RowN) from #tempTimeTable t1 where id is null
select ID, SUM([time]) from #tempTimeTable group by [ID]
```

What we are doing is:

1. Insert the data from the original table into a temp table with a new column added that indicates the row number.
2. Update the ID fields on the rows that are NULL and set it = to the highest ID from lower number rows only. it will look like this:

   ```
    1   time1
    1   time1
    1   time1
    1   time1
    2   time1
    2   time1
    2   time1
    3   time1
    3   time1
    3   time1
   ```
3. Retrieve the data after summing all the times for each ID together.

Let me know if this works for you.